# How do I override __getattr__ without breaking the default behavior?

Tags: python, getattr

How do I override the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method of a class without breaking the default behavior?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Overriding `__getattr__` should be fine -- `__getattr__` is only called as a last resort i.e. if there are no attributes in the instance that match the name. For instance, if you access `foo.bar`, then `__getattr__` will only be called if `foo` has no attribute called `bar`. If the attribute is one you don't want to handle, raise `AttributeError`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if some_predicate(name):
            # ...
        else:
            # Default behaviour
            raise AttributeError
```

However, unlike `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__` will be called first (only works for new style classes i.e. those that inherit from object). In this case, you can preserve default behaviour like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if some_predicate(name):
            # ...
        else:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

See [the Python docs for more](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Comment: Bah, your edit has the same thing I was showing in my answer, +1.

Comment: Cool, Python doesn't seem to like calling super's in `__getattr__` -- any ideas what to do? (`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`)

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to tell, but that looks like none of your superclasses define __getattr__.

Comment: This works with hasattr also because: "This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an exception or not." https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr

Comment: -1 This *does* modify default behavior.  Now you have an `AttributeError` without the context of the attribute in the exception args.

Comment: @wim what to do then?

Comment: @Max Either of the other 2 answers show how to keep context here. Unfortunately O.P. accepted the bad answer, and it got stuck to the top all those years ago..

Answer (score 41):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in ["b", "c"]:
            return 42
        raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                             (self.__class__.__name__, attr))
```

---

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
42
>>> a.b
42
>>> a.missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'missing'
>>> hasattr(a, "b")
True
>>> hasattr(a, "missing")
False
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just wanted to make sure I had the default message correct without digging around in the source.

Comment: I think that `self.__class__.__name__` should be used instead of `self.__class__` in case the class overrides `__repr__`

Comment: This is better than accepted answer, but it would be nice not to have to rewrite that code and potentially miss the upstream changes should the wording be modified or extra context added to the exception object in future.

Answer (score 28):

To extend Michael answer, if you want to maintain the default behavior using `__getattr__`, you can do it like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'something':
            return 42

        # Default behaviour
        return self.__getattribute__(name)
```

Now the exception message is more descriptive:

```
>>> foo.something
42
>>> foo.error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: @fed.pavlo are you sure? Maybe you mixed `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`?

Comment: my bad. I missed call to different method from self. ;(

Comment: Indeed @Michael's answer is incomplete without this answer

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return super().__getattribute__(name) ` just in case you also have a `__getattribute__` method in this class.

Comment: @pauleohare Yes, you might be right. Otherwise the `Foo.__getattribute__` would be invoked multiple times, unnecessarily