# Per instance dynamic fields django model

Tags: django, dynamic, model, field

I have a model with a JSON field or a link to a CouchDB document.  I can currently access the dynamic information in a way such as:

```
genericdocument.objects.get(pk=1) == genericdocument.json_field['sample subfield']
```

instead I would like to use

```
genericdocument.sample_subfield
```

to maintain compatibility with all the apps the project currently shares.

**UPDATE**

This is very close to what I'm trying to achieve: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/eav-django/1.0.0 but using Django standard fields instead.

Comment: I'm trying to expose a JSON field's keys as fields of a model.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7934577/497056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question helped me find the solution: [How do I override __getattr__ in Python without breaking the default behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405590/how-do-i-override-getattr-in-python-without-breaking-the-default-behavior)

```
class GenericDocument(models.Model):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        data = self.get_couchdb_data()
        if name in data.keys():
            return data[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

The dictionary returned by get_couchdb_data() is exposed as attributes of the model instance.

Answer (score 1):

does this help:

```
class GenericDocument(models.Model):
...
@property
def sample_subfield(self):
    return self.json_field['sample_subfield']
```

That should work ok for known "sample_subfields" if there are not too many.

If you want to be able to call `genericdocument.XXX` (where XXX can be *anything*), then you would have to overwrite `__getattribute__` in your model which I would not really put into consideratino since afaik Django does that itself.