# What's the best way to check if class instance variable is set in Python?

Tags: python

I have a variable which may or may not get a value in the instance:

```
class EC():
   __init__(self, a=False):
   ...
   if a: self.__var = ...
```

Later I want to check if the **__var** exists in the instance. Because prepending **__** to the name changes the internal name to **_EC__var** the checking code becomes a little bit messy:

```
if ''.join(['_',self.__class__.__name__,'__name']) in self.__dict__: ...
```

**Is code above considered normal or not? If not what are the preferred alternatives?**

One option I can think of is to give **__var** some value anyway, for example:

```
_no_value = object()
...
   def __init__(self, a):
      self.__var = _no_value
      ...
      if a: self.__var = ...
```

So later I can compare **__var** to **_no_value** instead of a mess with internal variables.

Comment: See the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function.

Comment: I've tried it, it has the the same problem (python 2.6.6). I have to use getattr(self, '_EC__var')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've forgotten the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python):

```
try:
    value = self.__var
except AttributeError:
    # do something else
```

If you're determined to use a sentinel, you can combine it with a class variable:

```
class EC():
    __var = object():
    ...
    if self.__var is not EC.__var:
        ...
```

Answer (score 15):

Just use hasattr(self, '_var') to see if it exists - it may be set to None but it will exist if hasattr says it does.

E.g.:

```
>>> class a():
...   def __init__(self):
...      self.a = 3
...      self._a_ = 4
...      self.__a__ = 'Fred'
...
>>> A=a()
>>> hasattr(a, 'a')
False
>>> hasattr(A, 'a')
True
>>> hasattr(A, '_a_')
True
>>> hasattr(A, '__a__')
True
>>> hasattr(A, '__b__')
False
>>>
```

Comment: This would work for single underscore, but it doen't work for double

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly, or understand what Python does to a `__var` double-underscore attribute on a class. No, it is not that simple.

Comment: As you can see from my expanded answer it works fine here with single and double underscores.

Comment: Double-underscore-prefix-*and-suffixed* members don't get mangled; they're treated as magic methods.

Comment: Learn something new every day - I would make 2 points though - 1) If you need to access an attribute externally it is probably better not to name it in a way that magically gets mangled specifically to keep it private and is probably better practice not to do so 2) if you absolutely __have__ to use that naming convention you would probably be better off and a lot clearer to use a class that overrides `__getattr__` as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405590/how-do-i-override-getattr-in-python-without-breaking-the-default-behavior

Answer (score 4):

Just set it to `None` *on the class*:

```
 class EC():
    __var = None

    __init__(self, a=False):
        ...
        if a: self.__var = ...
```

then test for `if self.__var is not None`.

If `None` should be a valid value for the attribute, use a *different* singleton sentinel:

```
_sentinel = object()

 class EC():
    __var = _sentinel

    __init__(self, a=False):
        ...
        if a: self.__var = ...
```

and test for `if self.__var is not _sentinel`.

This way, *all* references to `__var` are properly rewritten to include the class name.

The other path would be to not use double-underscore names for your attributes. `__var` should only be used for attributes you want to namespace to your specific class so that *subclasses* do not accidentally clobber it with their own attributes.

In other words, do not use double-underscore names unless you really understand what they are for and actually need it. Any code that is not part of a framework for wider consumption by unknown third parties? Just stick to single underscores instead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a simple way to check this out. This is the way I tried it.

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

        if self.c:
            self.d = "The variable exists"
        if 'd' in self.__dict__:
            print(self.d)
```

Now instantiate the above class:

```
t = Test('123', 'asd', True)
```

The above code outputs something like:

```
The variable exists
```

If you want to  see the contents of `self.__dict__`. Just type: `print(self.__dict__)`
The output of above code will be like:

```
{'a': '123', 'b': 'asd', 'c': True, 'd': 'The variable exists'}
```

All the instance variables are stored in the format of dictionary in self.**dict**

I tried this out in python 3.8.1 and python 2.6.6. It worked out. If there is any misconception with the answer, please report back by comment.