# Using eval in defing Python class data attributs

Tags: python, class, eval

I wonder if it possible to use eval to creates class data attributes. Something like following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init(self):
        matrix_names = ['F', 'B', 'H', 'Q', 'R', 'x', 'P']
        for matrix in matrix_names:
            print matrix
            operation = "self.%s = self.__matrix_read(%s)" %\
             (matrix, matrix)
            eval(operation)

    def __matrix_read(self, filename):
        return (read(".matrix/%s.csv"%filename))
```

In iPython I get:

```
File "<string>", line 1
   self.F = self.__matrix_read(F)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?!

Comment: use `exec` instead of `eval`. `eval` is to evaluate - just expressions, no statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* use eval for this. Other, better ways already exist if you wish to define attributes at runtime.

If you want the attributes defined and built at instantiation, use [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) as is recommended in [@PasteBT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20133508/2529026).

If you want the answers to be dynamically expandable, use [`__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) (good answer clarifying its behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405590/how-do-i-override-getattr-in-python-without-breaking-the-default-behavior)).

For example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.matrix_names = ['F', 'B', 'H', 'Q', 'R', 'x', 'P']

    def __matrix_read(self, name):
        return (read(".matrix/%s.csv"%filename))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.matrix_names:
            return self.__matrix_read(name)
```

Or, another way (IMHO cleaner, but YMMV):

```
class Test:
    # note that this is only called if the attr does not exist
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            with open(".matrix/{0}.csv".format(name)) as f:
                return f.read()
        except IOError:
            raise AttributeError("{0} does not exist".format(name))
```

(in python 3 replace `IOError` with `FileNotFoundError`). This way, you are not bound to a pre-built list of files, which may or may not be desirable depending on your application.

Answer (score 7):

You can use setattr build in function:

```
class Test:
    def __init(self):
        matrix_names = ['F', 'B', 'H', 'Q', 'R', 'x', 'P']
        for matrix in matrix_names:
            print matrix
            setattr(self, matrix, self.__matrix_read(matrix))
```