# Why there is infinite recursion loop risk in __getattribute__?

Tags: python

Refer to the second top answer to an existing question: [Difference between `__getattr__` vs `__getattribute__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute/3278104), which including code suggested by someone:

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self, mymin, mymax):
        self.mymin = mymin
        self.mymax = mymax
        self.current = None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__dict__[item] = 0
        return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return super(Count, self).__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count(1, 10)
print(obj1.mymin)
print(obj1.mymax)
print(obj1.current)
```

My question is:

When I run the code, it did *not* run into an infinite recursion deep (by ending with maximum recursion depth exceeded). Why? And, if I change the code `super(Count, self).__getattribute__(item)` to `super(object, self).__getattribute__(item)`, it did run into an infinite loop. Why again?

Please explain the reason with a detailed calling process.

Comment: Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405590/how-do-i-override-getattr-in-python-without-breaking-the-default-behavior

Comment: Unrelated, but updating the object's state - and eventually creating new attributes - on an attribute lookup is a very bad idea (unless your only caching some value in a protected attribute, but that's not the case here)

Comment: "When I run the code, it didn't run into an infinite recursion" => why should it ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I changed the line "return super(Count, self).__getattribute__(item)" to "return super(object, self).__getattribute__(item)
", and then it did.

Comment: You should never write `super(object, self)`. Ever. That can never be correct. There's nothing *above* `object`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I wonder what will actually happen inside, if I did change? what's the mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to make it simpler by breaking the `self.__dict__[item]` into 2 parts:

```
class Count(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('__getattr__:', item)
        d = self.__dict__
        print('resolved __dict__')
        d[item] = 0
        return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print('__getattribute__:', item)
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return super(Count, self).__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count()
print(obj1.current)
```

The output is

```
__getattribute__: current
__getattr__: current
__getattribute__: __dict__
resolved __dict__
0
```

Now, if we replace `super(Count, self)` with *the incorrect construct* `super(object, self)` the message is not printed. It is because `__getattribute__` *will* also mask the access to `__dict__`. However the `super` object will point to the base class of `object` which does not exist and hence our `__getattribute__` function will always throw `AttributeError`.

Now, after `__getattribute__` fails, `__getattr__` is being tried for it ... well, instead of just resolving `__dict__` to some value, it tries to *get it as an attribute - and ends up calling`__getattribute__` again.* Hence we get.

```
....
__getattribute__:  __dict__
__getattr__: __dict__
__getattribute__:  __dict__
__getattr__: __dict__
__getattribute__:  __dict__
__getattr__: __dict__
__getattribute__:  __dict__
__getattr__: __dict__
__getattribute__:  __dict__
__getattr__: __dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getattribute.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(obj1.current)
  File "getattribute.py", line 4, in __getattr__
    d = self.__dict__
  File "getattribute.py", line 4, in __getattr__
    d = self.__dict__
  File "getattribute.py", line 4, in __getattr__
    d = self.__dict__
  [Previous line repeated 328 more times]
  File "getattribute.py", line 8, in __getattribute__
    print('__getattribute__: ', item)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Had you used `setattr(self, item, 0)` instead of looking up `self.__dict__` this could have been "avoided":

```
class Count(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        setattr(self, item, 0)
        return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return super(object, self).__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count()
print(obj1.current)
```

of course such code would not have been correct - trying to access any  other attribute would have failed nevertheless.

Comment: Why __getattribute__ will mask the access to __dict__ ? I tried your code, I thought the code will never reach print statement but it will reach "d = self.__dict__".

Comment: I saw you added on the explanation, my question completely resolved, thank you!

Comment: it seems that 'object' doesn't have attribute  named __dict__ while any other class inherits it does have. when I use super(Count, self), self.__dict__ can be accessed as __dict__ is an attribute of class Count. Do I understand it correct?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "trying to access any other attribute would have failed nevertheless"