# Type hinting Python class with dynamic "any" attribute

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I have a Python class that supports "any" attribute through dynamic attribute resolution. This is one of the flavours of "attribute dict" pattern:

```
class ReadableAttributeDict(Mapping[TKey, TValue]):
    """
    The read attributes for the AttributeDict types
    """

    def __init__(
        self, dictionary: Dict[TKey, TValue], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> None:
        self.__dict__ = dict(dictionary)  # type: ignore
```

How can I tell Python type hinting that this class supports dynamic looking of attributes?

If I do

```
value = my_attribute_dict.my_var
```

Currently, PyCharm and Datalore are complaining:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'my_var for class 'MyAttributeDict'
```

Comment: Add `__getattr__(...)` definition, although PyCharm still does not infer attribute type even if you do set type hints like `def __getattr__(self, item: TKey) -> TValue:` (because of how .attr calls work). And aren't you just reimplementing dataclasses?

Comment: No this is is a developer experience improvement for a code that deals with a lot of nested dict data, JSON and so on.

Comment: ...But this doesn't change the level of nesting. Rather than a band-aid, the code base needs to be refactored to use dataclasses or named tuples; dicts infamously proliferate in Python projects and that effectively prevents any kind of static analysis (typing or otherwise).

Comment: @ReinderienI appreciate your advise. However I have been doing Python programming for 20 years, so I know what I am doing, and this does not apply to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of user sudden_appearance, adding a dummy `__getattribute__` solves the problem:

```py
class ReadableAttributeDict(Mapping[TKey, TValue]):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # Only implemented to make type hinting to stop complaining
        # Default behaviour
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405617/315168
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```